# node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts: error TS1005: '=' expected

Tags: angular

Earlier I was working with **Angular2.3.1** and just updated **package.json** file using **npm update --save** to get updated version of Angular2 which is **2.4.7**.

But it seems, for some reason, its breaking the code when I do **npm start**.

Its says

> node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts(39,52): error TS1005: '=' expected

Now, I wonder how to fix it?

Any idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After searching in google, came to know that **`latest version 2.5.43 of @types/jasmine`** is **not compatible** with **`typescript version 2.0.*`**.

***So had to upgrade typescript to `2.1.6`***.

**Read more here:**  https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/14569

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned on [Github](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/14569#issuecomment-279294265) you should downgrade your jasmine version for now.

In you **package.json** replace the current dependency with:

```
"@types/jasmine": "2.5.38"
```

After that run and NPM update in you command line

```
$ npm update
```

That's it your done, compilation errors should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure local TypeScript version is "2.1.6". In my case global TypeScript version was 2.2.1 and local version was 2.0.3. I changed local version for TypeScript (in package.json) to "2.1.6" and it worked fine.