# On running ng test cmd in angular6,getting Error

Tags: angular

I am using below versions on Win10
"@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
"typescript": "^2.7.2"

ERROR in node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts(138,47): error TS1005: ';' expected......

Comment: Please add the complete logs to the question. It's not really clear about what happened with the current details provided.

Comment: ERROR in node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts(138,47): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts(138,90): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts(138,104): error TS1005: ']' expected.
node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts(138,112): error TS1005: ',' expected.

Comment: Please refer below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42317687/node-modules-types-jasmine-index-d-ts-error-ts1005-expected

Comment: @sankar I tried with different versions for compatibility of both typescript & jasmine,but still getting error..:-(